# QuerySet has no field_names?

Tags: python, django

So I'm currently upgrading a Django app from 1.8 to 3.1 and came upon the following error:

`AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'field_names'`

I have tried to find deprecation information on this attribute and checked the QuerySet API for information but couldn't find anything relevant.

Has anybody gone through the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I missed out on any of the release notes from 1.8 to 2.0 or the deprecation timeline, it's not documented that QuerySet objects have an attribute 'field_names' that's basically a list of the names of the columns of the table the QuerySet belongs to.

Looking at the code from stable 1.8 and stable 1.9 of django/db/models/query.py you can see that the attribute was removed.

In case you were using that attribute and need to have it work after an update, you can use the Meta API of Django's Models like this:

`field_names = [f.name for f in Object._meta.get_fields()]`